# Script only working on one object in scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As you can see, I started with an object in a scene and attached a script to it along with other components. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ons5q.jpg

It looks barren due to there not actually being a model in there. However, when the game is started, it is created by another script in an object in the hierarchy. https://i.stack.imgur.com/eANS6.jpg

You can also see that the script works as expected and detects all the skinned mesh renderers and allows you to adjust the colors accordingly.

However, this is where the problem comes in.

When I duplicate this object the first object does what is expected of it but, the second one doesn't.

As you can see, there are no skinned mesh renderers in the list for the second object. https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7l94.jpg

Naturally, I put debug logs at the point where it detects the skinned mesh renderers to see what the issue is:

```
void OnMouseEnter()
{
    Debug.Log("Mouse Entered");
    foreach (SkinnedMeshRenderer element in skinnedMeshRenderersScan) //For 
every object it finds
    {
        Debug.Log("Detected: " + element);
        Debug.Log("Detected Color: " + selectedColor);
        element.material.color = selectedColor;
    }
}

void OnMouseExit()
{
    Debug.Log("Mouse Left");
    foreach (SkinnedMeshRenderer element in skinnedMeshRenderersScan) //For 
every object it finds
    {
        //Debug.Log("Detected: " + element);
        //Debug.Log("Detected Color: " + deselectedColor);
        element.material.color = deselectedColor;
    }
}
```

The first object notes that they're detected. https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HTPv.jpg

The second one simply pretends as if the debug log is not even there. https://imgur.com/alE76aY

I'm more than happy to elaborate in the event that you don't quite understand what it is I'm asking.

Many thanks in advance and sorry if my formatting is terrible I'm not the best at it.

I've tried searching for answers online but, I could not locate a solution to my rather unique problem.

The whole script is as follows:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TankController : MonoBehaviour
{

Vector3 targetPosition;
Vector3 lookAtTarget;

public Vector4 selectedColor;
public Vector4 deselectedColor;

Quaternion playerRot;

float rotSpeed = 2;
float speed = 3;

bool moving = false;
public bool Building = false;
public bool selected = false;
public bool CoolingDown = false;

public double CoolDown = .2;
public double original = .2;

MeshRenderer RenderMesh;
MeshRenderer RenderMeshParent;

SkinnedMeshRenderer[] skinnedMeshRenderersScan;
public List<SkinnedMeshRenderer> skinnedMeshRenderersList = new 
List<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    RenderMesh = GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>();
    RenderMeshParent = GetComponentInParent<MeshRenderer>();

    skinnedMeshRenderersScan = GetComponentsInChildren<SkinnedMeshRenderer> ();

    foreach (SkinnedMeshRenderer element in skinnedMeshRenderersScan) //For every object it finds
    {
        if (!skinnedMeshRenderersList.Contains(element)) //If it isn't already in this list
        {
            skinnedMeshRenderersList.Add(element); //Add to the list
        }
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        if (CoolingDown == false) //If not cooling down
        {
            SetTargetPosition();
            CoolingDown = true; //Set cooling down to true
        }
    }
    if (CoolingDown == true)
    {
        CoolDown -= Time.deltaTime; //Takes some time away
        if (CoolDown <= 0) //Checks if the cooldown is done yet
        {
            CoolingDown = false; //Sets cooling down to false
            CoolDown = original; //Cooldown timer is reset by equalling its original value
        }
    }
    if (moving)
        Move();
}

void SetTargetPosition()
{

    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
        {

            if (hit.collider.CompareTag("Hittable") == true && selected == true)
            {
                targetPosition = hit.point;
                lookAtTarget = new Vector3(targetPosition.x - transform.position.x,
                transform.position.y,
                targetPosition.z - transform.position.z);
                playerRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookAtTarget);
                moving = true;
            }

            if (hit.collider.CompareTag("Unit") == true)
            {

                Fighting self = GetComponentInChildren<Fighting>();

                Fighting other = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Fighting>();

                PlayerMaster playcheck = GetComponent<PlayerMaster>();

                if (CoolingDown == false) //If not cooling down
                {
                    if (gameObject.name == hit.collider.name)
                    {
                        if (selected == false)
                        {
                            selected = true;

                            RenderMesh.enabled = !RenderMesh.enabled;
                        }
                        else if (selected == true)
                        {
                            selected = false;

                            RenderMesh.enabled = !RenderMesh.enabled;
                        }
                    }

                    CoolingDown = true; //Set cooling down to true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void Move()
{
    if (Building == false)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation,
                                                playerRot,
                                                rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,
                                                targetPosition,
                                                speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (transform.position == targetPosition)
            moving = false;
    }
}

void OnMouseEnter()
{
    Debug.Log("Mouse Entered");
    foreach (SkinnedMeshRenderer element in skinnedMeshRenderersScan) //For every object it finds
    {
        Debug.Log("Detected: " + element);
        Debug.Log("Detected Color: " + selectedColor);
        element.material.color = selectedColor;
    }
}

void OnMouseExit()
{
    Debug.Log("Mouse Left");
    foreach (SkinnedMeshRenderer element in skinnedMeshRenderersScan) //For every object it finds
    {
        //Debug.Log("Detected: " + element);
        //Debug.Log("Detected Color: " + deselectedColor);
        element.material.color = deselectedColor;
    }
}
}
```

To recap, the expected result is that the second object (Or more) would work the same way the first object does.

In practice, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by putting the scans in the awake() method.